# レビューキューでフィルターを設定していて新着質問・回答が無くても赤丸(新着通知)が表示される

Tags: バグ

日本語版stackoverflowの右上には「レビューキュー」のアイコンがありますが、例えば「Java」をフィルターに設定していてそれに該当する質問・回答が無くても新着があることを示す赤丸が表示されます。フィルターも考慮した新着通知にして頂きたいです。

Comment: 「フィルターも考慮した結果にして欲しい」はどちらかというと機能追加の要望で、一方処理すべきタスクがないのに赤丸が表示され続けるのは7年前に MSE でも報告されていますが未だ解決には至っていません。 [Please don't red alert me for queues I've handled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302093)